# Postgres: ERROR: operator does not exist: inet << inet[] when doing a subquery

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem on postgres when asking if a given ip (inet type) is inside an array of inets.
I will provide step by step as to what I'm doing.

First I create the first table, that will contain the IP's to be contained inside inet blocks.

```
CREATE TABLE test_ips (
    id text,
    ip inet
);

INSERT INTO test_ips VALUES ('yeah', '134.53.100.2');
INSERT INTO test_ips VALUES ('nope', '135.53.100.2');
```

Then, I create a table that will contain inet blocks.

```
CREATE TABLE test_blocks (
    id    text PRIMARY KEY,
    block  inet[] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_blocks VALUES ('one', '{134.53.25.0/24,134.53.0.0/16}');
INSERT INTO test_blocks VALUES ('two', '{134.53.24.0/24}');
```

As you can see, I can get the full row when asking for the one with id 'one'.

```
SELECT blocks.block FROM test_blocks AS blocks WHERE blocks.id = 'one';
 id  |             block              
-----+--------------------------------
 one | {134.53.25.0/24,134.53.0.0/16}
(1 row)
```

And here I do the same query but asking only for the blocks.

```
SELECT blocks.block FROM test_blocks AS blocks WHERE blocks.id = 'one';
             block              
--------------------------------
 {134.53.25.0/24,134.53.0.0/16}
(1 row)
```

Here I ask for the ip table.

```
SELECT TI.id, TI.ip FROM test_ips AS TI;
  id  |      ip      
------+--------------
 yeah | 134.53.100.2
 nope | 135.53.100.2
(2 rows)
```

And here I ask for the row in which its IP is contained within any of the inet blocks provided (they are the same block array as asked just before), and it works fine.

```
SELECT TI.id, TI.ip FROM test_ips AS TI WHERE TI.ip << ANY ('{134.53.25.0/24,134.53.0.0/16}');
  id  |      ip      
------+--------------
 yeah | 134.53.100.2
(1 row)
```

The thing is, that when I try to ask about that same IP inside the same block, but giving the block as a subquery I end up getting an error.

```
SELECT TI.id, TI.ip FROM test_ips AS TI WHERE TI.ip << ANY (SELECT blocks.block FROM test_blocks AS blocks WHERE blocks.id = 'one');
ERROR:  el operador no existe: inet << inet[]

Translated: ERROR: operator does not exist: inet << inet[]
```

Any tips on why this is happenning or how could I solve this?

As Abelisto suggested, I tried a new consult:

```
SELECT TI.id, TI.ip FROM test_ips AS TI WHERE TI.ip << ANY (ARRAY(SELECT blocks.block FROM test_blocks AS blocks WHERE blocks.id = 'one'));
ERROR:  no se pudo encontrar un tipo de array para el tipo de dato inet[]

TRANSLATED: ERROR: Couldn't find a type of array for data type inet[]
```

As Abelisto suggested again, I first unnested my blocks. This time it worked.

```
SELECT TI.id, TI.ip FROM test_ips AS TI WHERE TI.ip << ANY (SELECT unnest(blocks.block) FROM test_blocks AS blocks WHERE blocks.id = 'one');
  id  |      ip      
------+--------------
 yeah | 134.53.100.2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Works fine for me on the simple test. Try to explicitly specify the array: `TI.ip << ANY (ARRAY(SELECT ...));`

Comment: I just tried as your first comment suggested and I couldn't get it to work. I edited the post to show what it said.

Comment: Ups, I missed that you have the field type `inet[]`, not simple `inet`. It should work: `TI.ip << ANY (SELECT unnest(blocks.block) FROM test_blocks AS blocks WHERE blocks.id = 'one');` The thing was that you try to compare the value with array of arrays, not with just array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the your table `test_blocks` the field `block` have array type `inet[]` and the error can be reproduced by the simple example:

```
select 1 where 1 = any(select x from (values(array[1])) as t(x));
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
```

It is because we are trying to compare the integer `1` with array of integers `array[1]`. So we should to unnest the array to the set of values:

```
select 1 where 1 = any(select unnest(x) from (values(array[1])) as t(x));
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

In your case the condition should look like:

```
TI.ip << ANY (SELECT unnest(blocks.block) FROM test_blocks AS blocks WHERE blocks.id = 'one');
```